# Path prefix to remove start of suffix

Tags: directory, path

I have a program that wants to look for library files in a subdirectory of the directory I specify with an environment variable. Is it possible to put in my specified directory a path that ignores the first subdirectory that is being appended? Here's what I mean.

My folder structure

```
/usr/lib64/[All the library files]
```

Program looks at

```
$MAGICK_HOME/lib/[All the library files]
```

where I can manipulate `$MAGICK_HOME`.

So if I set `MAGICK_HOME=/usr` it will look at `/usr/lib/[library files]`, which is wrong.
If I set `MAGICK_HOME=/usr/lib64` it will look at `/usr/lib/lib64/[library files]` which is also wrong.

If it were the other way round, I could ignore the last directory specified in the prefix path by starting my suffix with a `../` to get back from the outermost directory.
What can I put as my `MAGICK_HOME` to specify the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 situations of interest:

#### Your app is reading the libraries of `/usr/lib64`, but you want it to read to libraries of `$MAGICK_HOME/lib`:

If you are compiling you application, you could add some `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` rules so that the binary searches for libs in `$ORIGIN/../lib64`. Otherwise, you could add `$MAGICK_HOME/lib` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a shell script that starts your binary so the dynamic linker searches that path for binaries, or you could use `ldconfig` to add a specific library to `/etc/ld.so.cache`

---

#### Your app is reading the libraries of `$MAGICK_HOME/lib` instead of `/usr/lib64`

When ld.so dynamically links, it searches:

- `DT_RPATH` field compiled in the ELF-binary (if `DT_RUNPATH` doesn't exist).  This will usually be an absolute path, or a path relative to the location of the binary (`$ORIGIN`).  I don't think an environment variable like `$MAGICK_HOME` can influence it.
- `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable  (unless being run in secure-execution mode)
- `DT_RUNPATH` field compiled in the ELF-binary (similar to `DT_RPATH` above).
- `/etc/ld.so.cache`, which contains a compiled list of candidate shared objects.
- default paths of `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.  On some architetures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects are `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`. If the binary was linked with the `-z nodeflib` linker option, this step is skipped.

Since `/usr/lib64` is probably in the default path, I suspect the program is manipulating `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when it starts, or used `ldconfig` to add libraries into `/etc/ld.so.cache` during installation. This would cause the `$MAGICK_HOME/lib` libraries to be found first.  If you can prevent it from doing these things, then it should fallback to `/usr/lib64`.

You can use `readelf` to see if it was compiled for a specific `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH`, but I don't think that's the case because it sounds like an environment variable influences the linking and these options cannot (AFAIK) be influenced by the environment.

---

#### Your app is failing to start because it can't find the libraries installed in `/usr/lib64`

If the problem is not that it's loading the wrong binaries, but instead it's not loading any binaries, then it could be that `/usr/lib64` is not in your default path.  We'd need to know about your distro and architecture to help further in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I think it may be a failing of the program that is trying to use the library, and not so much the location of the library files. I'm on CentOS trying to install Wand: https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/ .
After installing `ImageMagick-devel` using `yum` and copying the library files to a place where I could specify the exact library directory I'm still having the same issue. I will add the trace to the question description.

Comment: Actually, it seems it has fixed itself, when looking back at the traces it seems there was another library interfering with imports. Now I get:
DelegateError: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 9.25] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/mrod/magick-16886b3woG5lrbXG3%d' '-f/tmp/mrod/magick-16886eW1PKJ1qhmUO' '-f/tmp/mrod/magick-16886EyTqaCf7AM7z'': (null) @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171